# asp.net inserting data into SQL Server db in while loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, import

I want to import data from Excel worksheet into SQL Server database (2008). I have successfully tested code for getting data from xls file. However, I am not able insert these data into db table. Here is the part of the code:

```
        while (ctecka.Read())
        {
            exJmeno = ctecka[0].ToString();
            exPrijmeni = ctecka[1].ToString();
            Response.Write(exJmeno + " " + exPrijmeni + " ");
            pridano = vlozSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

**ctecka** is DbDataReader object and it contains data from excel worksheet

**exJmeno** and **exPrijmeni** are strings and data from columns are inserted there

Problem:

*Response.write* writes onto page the data I need

*vlozSQL.ExecuteNonQuery* ignores data in (exJmeno and exPrijmeni) and inserts empty          columns into table in database

here are some definitions:

```
string InsertSQL = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname) VALUES (@name,@surname)";
vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", exJmeno);
vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", exPrijmeni);
```

**EDIT**

```
    string exJmeno = "";
    string exPrijmeni = "";
    string InsertSQL = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname) VALUES (@name,@surname)";
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(SQLpripoj);
    SqlCommand vlozSQL = new SqlCommand(InsertSQL, sqlconn);
    vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", exJmeno);
    vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", exPrijmeni);

    try
    {
        spojeni.Open();
        DbDataReader ctecka = prikaz.ExecuteReader();

        sqlconn.Open();
        while (ctecka.Read())
        {
            exJmeno = ctecka[0].ToString();
            exPrijmeni = ctecka[1].ToString();
            Response.Write(exJmeno + " " + exPrijmeni + " ");
            pridano = vlozSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        spojeni.Close();
        sqlconn.Close();
        Label2.Text = pridano.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: We need to see more code to understand what is going on, especially the SqlClient code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since strings are not mutable in C#, your assignments in the loop won't actually change the parameters, you'll have to add them each time. You'll need to do something like;

```
while (ctecka.Read())
{
    exJmeno = ctecka[0].ToString();
    exPrijmeni = ctecka[1].ToString();
    Response.Write(exJmeno + " " + exPrijmeni + " ");
    vlozSQL.Parameters.Clear();
    vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", exJmeno);
    vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", exPrijmeni);
    pridano = vlozSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

move this part of code in while loop

```
vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", exJmeno);
vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", exPrijmeni);
```

for ex:

```
while (ctecka.Read())
    {
        exJmeno = ctecka[0].ToString();
        exPrijmeni = ctecka[1].ToString();
        vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", exJmeno);
         vlozSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", exPrijmeni);
        Response.Write(exJmeno + " " + exPrijmeni + " ");
        pridano = vlozSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply, however the line vlozSQL.Parameters.Clear();
is essential (by Joachim Isaksson)